# USB-C Charging doesn't charge UP while suspended (i7-8565U Whisky Lake)

Tags: hp, battery, usb-c, charging

My HP Spectre X360 13 suspends fine now that I have installed the 4.19 kernel - but the thing is it doesn't charge UP while suspended. That's not to say it doesn't "charge" while suspended - it literally retains the same amount of charge that it did when it entered suspend mode. If the battery is at 40% and a I put it in suspend and come back to it 1 hour later or 3 days later or however much time later it will be exactly 40%. Whatever controls the charging seems to lock in the maximum charge to the amount it was when the suspend was initialized. If I power the machine off it of course charges, and it charges while the machine is on - so I've had to just leave my machine on when I don't want to shut down so it will charge up!

I have a feeling this will be handled in a future kernel update or something like that - but if anyone has an idea of how to fix it now I'd sure love to hear it.

Comment: Why would what happens in a suspended state be in any way related to the suspended OS? Does it charge if you do the same in Windows? Unlikely. UEFI is the problem, I suspect. Try to find an update.

Comment: Check your BIOS options - there may be siomething about "Battery" or "Power".

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It *does* charge if it's in Windows. It's definitely related to the OS because Whisky Lake has a whole bunch power related issues that are only being addressed now in builds of Kernel 4.19 - I suspect this is one of them. BIOS is up to date and I've tried changing everything in the BIOS that could be even remotely related to this without luck.

Comment: @waltinator Already tried everything in the BIOS that seemed even remotely related to power management. There IS something in there that is particularly interesting - this machine has a feature to peg the maximum charge amount a specific value (50%, 80%, or 100%) where values lower than 100% are meant to keep stress off the battery and make it last through more charge cycles. I have a strong feeling this feature is what is preventing the charging during suspend under Linux (EG, during suspend some sort of reporting isn't being interacted with between the kernel and the BIOS?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved with a kernel update some time after posting the question.